# How do vertically align a table in CSS where the height and width are percentages

Tags: css, html-table, formatting, vertical-alignment

I've looked everywhere on this forum for a way to vertically align a table in CSS that works for all browsers, IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari and found this solution, below (which works) but only if you specify the PIXELS of a table.
Since people have different size screens it's not that useful for a text box.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dead Center</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .dead_center {
       width:270px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="dead_center" border=5>
      <tr>
        <td>My centered table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How could you modify the above so that your table is just say 50% width of the screen and no height specified. I.e. whatever length of text it is will show up vertically centered.

[Here's the page I'm working on fixing up.](http://internettrafficrevealed.com)

What I'd like to do is take the two tables and format them so they fit nicely in the center of the page. The left side has the text/copy and the right side is the GetResponse form. Both should be vertically aligned so it looks nice. Right now they're at the top.

Comment: Adding Height = 100% fixed it ! thanks! OMG that was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to add height="100%" to your largest outer table. This will vertically center your box.

However, I would recommend using divs instead of tables and having each rounded box positioned left and right. Tables is bad practice for web layout.

In either case, when you are viewing on smaller screens you will need to use media queries to adjust your styles.

Comment: Awesome! it works perfectly now. I'm shocked at how simple that little adjustment makes a world of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to achieve is a much responsive webpage. My advice is that you should take the table tag out (table-less web implementation) and just use div or section tags. And then you can use media queries to make your page responsive or you can use some CSS3 frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Yeah, however, it won't be as compatible with older browsers. My version works with old browsers as well as fancy new ones.  I'm curious how you would rewrite the page without using tables. Every time I try doing that it seems more complicated than its worth. Do you have a code sample I could look at? Thanks.